# Need help fixing memory leak - NSMutableString

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring, nsmutablestring

Have been playing around with instruments with not much luck in figuring out how to solve this memory leak.

Firstly the code:

```
-(NSString *) randomizeHint:(NSString *) wordToShuffle{

    NSMutableString * outputstring = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[wordToShuffle length]];
    NSMutableSet * usedNumberSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[wordToShuffle length]];

    for (int i=0; i<[wordToShuffle length]; i++) {
        int randomnum = arc4random()%[wordToShuffle length];

        while ([usedNumberSet containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnum]]==YES) {
            randomnum = arc4random()%[wordToShuffle length];
        }

        [usedNumberSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnum]];
        [outputstring appendFormat:@"%c",[wordToShuffle characterAtIndex:randomnum]];
    }

    CCLOG(@"outputstring is:%@",outputstring);
    return outputstring;

 }
```

Instruments is giving me the following:

`Leaked Object = NSCFString, Responsible Library = Foundation, Responsible Frame = -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithCapacity:]`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code seems right. And in this case `NSMutableString` is autoreleased. Are you sure this leak is coming in above code?

Comment: Try `return [outputstring copy]`?

Comment: It seems to me that if you leak an object anywhere, Instruments points back to the location where it was created.  Could it be that the caller of this routine is leaking the returned string?

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. InderKumarRathore - I thought NSMutableString was autoreleased too, that's why stumped. ZhangChn - I don't want to have to explicitly release it outside of this method, its a local variable, so the copy won't do it for me. Phillips Mills - Yes,unfortunately this is the last element in the stack trace in my code before instruments goes off into standard libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use a mutable string... especially since your return type is NSString.  Just use stringByAppendingFormat:

```
-(NSString *) randomizeHint:(NSString *) wordToShuffle{

    NSString * outputstring = @"";

    NSMutableSet * usedNumberSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:[wordToShuffle length]];

    for (int i=0; i<[wordToShuffle length]; i++) {
        int randomnum = arc4random()%[wordToShuffle length];

        while ([usedNumberSet containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnum]]==YES) {
            randomnum = arc4random()%[wordToShuffle length];
        }

        [usedNumberSet addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnum]];

        // just set outputstring like so... no need to worry about a leaky mutable string then
        outputstring = [outputstring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c",
                    [wordToShuffle characterAtIndex:randomnum]];
    }


    return outputstring;

}
```

Comment: +1 for better conduct (i.e., avoiding mutables whenever possible).  Also, if your leak *is* in this section of code, this will probably help.  It's really hard to leak `NSString` objects.

Comment: i'll give this a try and get back to you. Thanks for help.

Comment: There have been times where I thought I needed an NSMutableString and each time I end up refactoring it out later.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at where the returned string is used. Possibly you are retaining it and dealloc'ing the object that retained the string without first releasing the retained string. Instruments will still point to this section of code as being the 'leaked' object. The hardest part is locating the 'leaker'. And yes, you can leak a string, I just wrote the recipe for it.