# Memory leak reported by instrument. Can't understand why

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

Instruments is telling that the following method is leaking memory when creating the mutable string. Can anybody tell me why? I am using ARC on iOS 8 XCode 6.2.

```
 - (NSString *)capitalizeFirstLetter {
        if (self.length == 0) {
            return self;
        }
        NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.lowercaseString];
        [string replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:[self substringToIndex:1].capitalizedString];
        return string;
    }
```

Comment: Please consider using `-[NSString rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:]`, as not all letters are coded as one character.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what caused the leak, but if you want to only avoid it you can change your method to:

```
- (NSString *)capitalizeFirstLetter {
    if (self.length == 0) {
        return self;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self substringToIndex:1].capitalizedString, [self substringFromIndex:1]];
}
```

also you could review the answeres here [Need help fixing memory leak - NSMutableString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508699/need-help-fixing-memory-leak-nsmutablestring)

Comment: I change the implementation to the one you have suggested and Instruments stills reports a memory leak. Could it be that Instruments reports where the object that has been leaked was created but not actual code that is leaking? It is really hard to track the cause.

Comment: You could try this: do not call the function and see if something still leaks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the memory leak! Could you please post the call of this method?